# PHP - call function in object with set_error_handler()

Tags: php

I am trying to use this in my page class. I only just started using objects in PHP so I'm still a little clueless (but learning as much as I can). This is in my `page()` function (so called when there is a new instance of page)

```
set_error_handler('$this->appendError');
```

This is causing an error

> Warning: set_error_handler() expects the argument (appendError) to be a valid callback

Now how do I set a class internal function whilst passing the function as a string. Is this not possible? Should I use a normal function which then calls the class function and sends through all arguments? This sounds a little cumbersome to me.

Or have I missed the problem? I've tried making my appendError return a string, and echo.. but it still isn't playing nice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Few problems with that.

First:

```
'$this->appendError'
```

is a nogo.  It doesn't interpret $this to the current class, php interprets it as the string '$this'.

Second: Try

```
set_error_handler(array($this, 'appendError'));
```

If that doesn't work, replace $this with the classname and use it statically.

Comment: @ray, thanks for this, i can't use set_error_handler("class::method"); because of php strict standard non static method i need to set $class = new class();   set_error_handler($class->method); //this don't work

Answer (score 1):

Read the [php.net callback documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback). I think example 3 is closest to what you want:

```
// Type 3: Object method call
$obj = new MyClass();
call_user_func(array($obj, 'myCallbackMethod'));
```