# set_exception_handler in codeigniter - how to use?

Tags: codeigniter, exception

I have a code similar to the following which is not working.

```
class Abc extends CI_Controller {

    static function exception_handler(Exception $ex)
    {       
        var_dump($ex);
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        set_exception_handler('exception_handler');     
    }       

    function Index()
    {

        throw new Exception('hehe');
    }
}
```

I get

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: set_exception_handler() expects the argument
>   (exception_handler) to be a valid callback

How to use set_exception_handler in codeigniter

Comment: read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319762/php-call-function-in-object-with-set-error-handler

Answer (score 3):

Since `exception_handler` is a function inside a class, it should be:

```
set_exception_handler(array('self','exception_handler'));
```

Or

set_exception_handler(array('Abc','exception_handler'));

Answer (score 3):

Set_exception_handler always expects full name class, including the namespace and omits the "use instruction" for use others namespaces.

In your case the fullname is:  'CI_Controller:exception_handler'

Therefore the correct call is:  set_exception_handler('CI_Controller:exception_handler');

If you had one namespace e.g. namespace App;

The correct call is:  set_exception_handler('App\CI_Controller:exception_handler');

Comment: This was helpful.  I found that, for a static function, you can also use `set_exception_handler(array(MyClass::class, 'exception_handler'))` to get the fully qualified class name.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Index()
{
    function ExceptionHandler($e) use($this)
    {
        $this->load->view('error', $this->sharedData);
    }

    set_exception_handler('ExceptionHandler');

    throw new Exception('hehe');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use method of the instantiated Object with access level is public.

```
final class MyException
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     * trigger getErrorTypesFromDefinedConstant method
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Set global exception handler
        set_exception_handler(array($this, 'globalException'));
    }

    public function globalException($e)
    {
        // Your code to handle exception
    }
}
```